# Magento2 hide flat rate shipping for particular category products

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How can I hide flatrate shipping for particular category products?

Any advice will be appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a plugin for CollectRates for Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate. I would do it like this:

app/code/StackExchange/HideFlatRateForCategories/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
>
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
        <plugin name="HideFlatRateForSomeCategories"
                type="StackExchange\HideFlatRateForCategories\Plugin\HideFlatRateForSomeCategories"
        />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/HideFlatRateForCategories/Plugin/HideFlatRateForSomeCategories.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\HideFlatRateForCategories\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class HideFlatRateForSomeCategories
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private Session $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $flatrate, $result)
    {
        // enter the categories you want to exclude here:
        $categories = [4, 6];
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();

        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (!empty(array_intersect($item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds(), $categories))) {

                return false;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hello it worked fine. Can u suggest me something on how can I stop a particular category product from adding to cart when another exists? Like if A category product is present you can't add B category product & vice verse...